# How to use different routes for a same page in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next

Next.js manages routing from the `/pages` folder, but I would like to use two different routes for a same component.

I want to have an `/about` route and a `/a-propos` route that both render the component in the `about.js` file.

```
mywebpage.com/about         To show -> pages/about/index.js
```

and

```
mywebpage.com/a-propos      To show -> pages/about/index.js
```

Is there an official way of achieving that?

Comment: Just make the index.js file in a seperate folder (like container) and use it in both pages (about.js and a-propos.js)

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor your page component into a more general component directory, add a folder called `a-propos` to your `/pages` directory and then reference the general component from both `/pages/about/` and `/pages/a-propos`.

If you want to intercept routing requests and do something more exotic, take a look at the docs for [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Answer (score 0):

The official way to do this is with rewrites:

[NextJS Rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/a-propos',
        destination: '/about',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```